# unpacking result of split() into fewer variables than specified

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been doing a bit of code where I enter some numbers,split them up into separate variables and then orders those numbers, and i can split them up fine, but when I try to split into only 4 (for example) numbers (less than the amount of variables) it returns the error 'not enough variables to unpack'. I want it so I can input the any amount of numbers (up to the max, which in this case is 10) and it will sort the given numbers, print them, but it wont print the other variables.

I've so far done this:

```
a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j = input("enter up to 10 digits").split()
nlist=(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j)
def bubbleSort():
    for l in range(len(nlist)-1,0,-1):
        for k in range(l):
            if nlist[k]>nlist[k+1]:
                temp = nlist[k]
                nlist[k] = nlist[k+1]
                nlist[k+1] = temp

bubbleSort(nlist)
print(nlist)
```

I know this is probably has a lot of mistakes, so if anyone could help me find a much more efficient/correct way of doing this, I would greatly appreciate it.

Also, just wondering, how could i do it so once i`ve inputed the numbers i can then find the mean, mode, medium and range of the numbers?

Comment: `nlist = list(map(int, input().split()))` Is the most common idiom for doing this.

Comment: Then you don't need to unpack at all. Keep the list from `split`.

Comment: split your input into a list, and use the built-in sort function

Comment: `print(sorted(map(int,input().split())))`

Comment: Also your instructions should probably be 'enter up to 10 digits'. What if someone wants to enter ten one hundreds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you want to get the input as a list

```
input_list = map(int, input("enter up to 10 numbers").split())
```

Then you want to sort it:

```
input_list.sort()
```

or if you want to keep a version with original order :

```
sorted_list = sorted(input_list)
```

Then you can print it:

```
print(sorted_list)
```

If you want to limit your user to 10 input, use a loop for the input :

```
continue_ = True
while continue_:
    input_list = input("enter up too 10 numbers").split()
    continue_ = len(input_list) >= 10
```

The final code is :

```
continue_ = True
while continue_:
    input_list = map(int, input("enter up too 10 numbers").split())
    continue_ = len(input_list) >= 10
sorted_list = sorted(input_list)
print(sorted_list)
```

Comment: Before sorting, you need to convert the input `str`s to `int`

Comment: Thanks, also added the 10 input limitation

Comment: Your final code has both `.sort()` and `sorted()` calls. You should pick one, or note in the code as a comment that they are alternatives

Comment: Indead thanks, decided to "pick one" because alternatives are explained before. Final code is juste a copy/paste example.

Answer (score 4):

It seems you're confused on what is required of you to use split. On your first two lines you are unpacking a list, then immediately reconstructing the list:

```
a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j = input("enter numbers").split()
nlist=(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j) # note you actually want [] not ()
```

If you replace () around your nlist with `[]` (since you are mutating the list) that would be equivalent to the following for your valid cases

```
nlist = input("enter numbers").split()
```

You don't need to unpack at all. Note, however, that `nlist` will still be a sequence of `str`s, if you want a list of `int`s you have a couple of options.

```
# 1) list comprehension
nlist = [int(i) for i in input("enter numbers").split()]

# 2) map
nlist = map(int, input("enter numbers").split())
```

---

Additional issues include:

1) You are defining bubbleSort to take zero arguments, but then calling it with one. nlist is a global which isn't great. You'd be better off dividing your code into a couple of functions

```
def bubbleSort(nlist):
    ...

def main():
   nlist = # choose from the above options
   bubbleSort(nlist)
   print(nlist)

if __name__ == '__main__': # only run if module is being run directly
    main()
```

2) You can't assign to elements of a tuple. A tuple is a sequence surrounded by `()` as you have in your original code for `nlist`. This won't work

```
>>> items = (1, 2, 3)
>>> items [0] = 4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
```

use a list instead by surrounding the sequence with `[]`

```
>>> items = [1, 2, 3]
>>> items [0] = 4 # fine
```

3) Multiple assignments in python mean you don't have to use the old swap idiom. instead of code like

```
temp = a
a = b
b = temp
```

You can just write

```
a, b = b, a
```

This technique can clean up your code a bit where you are moving elements around the list

Answer (score 0):

If that's your goal and this is not a practice exercise you are doing then do this:

`nums = sorted([int(num) for num in input('Enter the numbers here:').split()])`

Answer (score 0):

Other answers have good explanation. I am just showing a way. What are you trying to achieve can be done by this way:

```
print(sorted(map(int,input().split())))
```

Short explanation:

- `input` takes input string of numbers separated by spaces
- `split()` will split those into list of number strings (still `str`)
- `map(int, ...)` will convert those strings to `int` (now they are numbers)
- `sorted` will sort the numbers
- `print` will print

And here is a fancy version of the above to restrict input to 10 numbers:

```
print('Enter 10 numbers. Press Enter after each number:')
print(sorted(int(f()) for f in [input]*10))
```

Comment: thanks a lot for this, deffinetly a much better way for doing what i was trying and it works well